# Who can see banner "<branch> had pushes <x> minutes ago" on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Git newbie question. If I push to GitHub from a branch and go to the GitHub UI I see a banner saying " had pushes  minutes ago". I'm wondering if that's visible to everyone on the repo or just me (assuming I'm the only one who's contributed to the branch)?

Comment: Easy to check: logout from GitHub and view your repository as anonymous/guest/not logged-in user.

Comment: it's a private repo so I can't see it if I'm logged out

Comment: If you can’t even test it then it doesn’t practically make a difference.

Comment: I'm wondering if coworkers can see it. I personally can't test that but I'd like to know what they see